# XAML ControlTemplate from string

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I am creating a series of ControlTemplates to be displayed on a WPF control from some strings. I use this code:

```
string theTemplate = @"<ControlTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
                <Grid Name=""RootElement"" RenderTransformOrigin=""0.5,0.5"" >
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX=""1"" ScaleY=""1"" />
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name=""CommonStates"">
                            <VisualState Name=""Normal"">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime=""00:00:00"" 
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName=""RootElement"" 
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty=""(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"" 
                                                                To=""1"" Duration=""0:0:0.1"" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime=""00:00:00"" 
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName=""RootElement"" 
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty=""(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"" 
                                                                To=""1"" Duration=""0:0:0.1"" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name=""MouseOver"">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime=""00:00:00"" 
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName=""RootElement"" 
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty=""(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"" 
                                                                To=""1.5"" Duration=""0:0:0.1"" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime=""00:00:00"" 
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName=""RootElement"" 
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty=""(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"" 
                                                                To=""1.5"" Duration=""0:0:0.1"" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Ellipse Height=""{Binding Symbol.Size}"" Width=""{Binding Symbol.Size}"" Fill=""{Binding Symbol.Color}""  Stroke=""Black"">

                </Ellipse>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>";
System.IO.StringReader stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(theTemplate);
System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
ControlTemplate ct = (ControlTemplate)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(reader);
```

That all works well. The problem is when instead of using the Ellipse I try using my custom Shape. In a regular WPF Window I use this reference:

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
```

and then instead of Ellipse I can do:

```
<custom:Square Size=""{Binding Symbol.Size}"" Fill=""{Binding Symbol.Color}"" Stroke=""Black"" RotationAngle=""0"">
</custom:Square>
```

Now, when I add that line to the string "theTemplate" it does now work. The reason I think is because I don't have that reference in. I have tried adding the references in different places like:

```
<ControlTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" >
```

and did not work. I also tried:

```
<custom:Square Size=""{Binding Symbol.Size}"" Fill=""{Binding Symbol.Color}"" Stroke=""Black"" RotationAngle=""0"" xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" >
</custom:Square>
```

And did not like it either.

Sooo, any suggestions? How can I reference my custom shapes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `XamlReader` you usually need to fully qualify your CLR `xmlns`, i.e. add the assembly.

e.g.

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2;assembly=WpfApplication2"
```